# Reclaim tab bar space

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I hide the tab bar of my app by using `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true` in `viewWillAppear`. This works successfully to hide the tab bar, but the web view on my screen doesn't take up that space (see screenshot). I believe I have AutoLayout successfully setup. How can I make the webview take up the space where the tab bar was? Below is an example of my code.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if (segue.identifier == "segToTermsOfService") {
        let seg = segue.destinationViewController as! WebViewVC

        seg.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true

        seg.pageType = "Terms"
    }

    if (segue.identifier == "segToPrivacyPolicy") {
        let seg = segue.destinationViewController as! WebViewVC

        seg.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true

        seg.pageType = "Privacy"
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Before pushing **Privacy Policy view controller**, in **Setting view controller**,
add the following line

```
privacyPolicyVCInstance.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES
```

It will hide the tab bar and will make the Privacy Policy view controller to fill the whole screen

Comment: See edit above. I'm using your suggestion, but still seeing the same result. Can you please verify I'm using the code correctly. Many thanks!